# How to group data order by continuous timeline without non-unique identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, date, grouping

I have data that shows, by date, which properties of an item were active. For example, on day 2 only the property with ID 1 was active and on day 4 another property with ID 2 was also activated. What I need to show is, which for how long every combination of properties was active.

See code. I am new to Oracle SQL and I know what I want to do but I don't know the functions to use. Also I have no idea what to search for. I the code there are 2 different approaches. Both yield the same result which is not wrong but also not what I want.

```
with mydata as (    
  SELECT
    DECODE(rownum,
      1,to_date('19.09.2019'), 2,to_date('20.09.2019'), 3,to_date('21.09.2019'),
      4,to_date('22.09.2019'), 5,to_date('23.09.2019'), 6,to_date('24.09.2019'),
      7,to_date('25.09.2019'), 8,to_date('26.09.2019'), 9,to_date('27.09.2019'),
      10,to_date('28.09.2019'), 11,to_date('29.09.2019'), 12,to_date('30.09.2019'),
      13,to_date('01.10.2019'), 14,to_date('02.10.2019'), 15,to_date('03.10.2019'),
      16,to_date('04.10.2019'), 17,to_date('05.10.2019'), 18,to_date('06.10.2019'),
      19,to_date('07.10.2019'), 20,to_date('08.10.2019'), 21,to_date('09.10.2019'),
      22,to_date('10.10.2019'), 23,to_date('11.10.2019'), 24,to_date('12.10.2019'),
      25,to_date('13.10.2019')
    ) AS check_date,
    DECODE(rownum,
      1,'1', 2,'1', 3,'1', 4,'1;2', 5,'1;2', 6,'1;2', 7,'1', 8,'1', 9,'1;3',
      10,'1;3', 11,'1;3', 12,'3', 13,'3', 14,'3', 15,'4', 16,'4', 17,'4;5',
      18,'4;5', 19,'4;5', 20,'4', 21,'4', 22,'4', 23,'6', 24,'6', 25,'6'
    ) AS id_list
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 25
)

-- select * from mydata;
-- select id_list, min(check_date) as valid_from, max(check_date) as valid_to 
-- from mydata group by id_list order by 2;

select 
  id_list, 
  min(valid_from), 
  max(valid_to) 
from (
  select id_list,
    min(check_date) over (
      partition by id_list 
      ORDER BY id_list 
      ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) as valid_from,
    max(check_date) over (
      partition by id_list 
      ORDER BY id_list 
      ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) as valid_to
  from mydata 
  order by 2
) 
group by id_list 
order by 2;
```

The result is this:

```
id_list     valid_from              valid_to
1           19.09.2019 00:00:00     26.09.2019 00:00:00
1;2         22.09.2019 00:00:00     24.09.2019 00:00:00
1;3         27.09.2019 00:00:00     29.09.2019 00:00:00
3           30.09.2019 00:00:00     02.10.2019 00:00:00
4           03.10.2019 00:00:00     10.10.2019 00:00:00
4;5         05.10.2019 00:00:00     07.10.2019 00:00:00
6           11.10.2019 00:00:00     13.10.2019 00:00:00
```

What I want: the first line of output should have `VALID_TO date 21.09.2019` because from `22.9.2019` the next line/combination is valid.  Basically I don't know how to handle overlap.

Comment: For some reason the first line of code was not included: ´´´with mydata as ( ´´´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the gaps-and-island problem. You can compare the rank of records by `check_date` againts their rank in `id_list` partitions to decide to which group they belong.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    id_list, 
    MIN(check_date) valid_from, 
    MAX(check_date) valid_to
FROM (
    SELECT
        id_list,
        check_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY check_date) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_list ORDER BY check_date) rn2
    FROM mydata
) x 
GROUP BY id_list, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY 2
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab0df296881876edc986489b56fcf5b7)** with your sample data returns:

```
ID_LIST | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO 
:------ | :--------- | :--------
1       | 19-SEP-19  | 21-SEP-19
1;2     | 22-SEP-19  | 24-SEP-19
1       | 25-SEP-19  | 26-SEP-19
1;3     | 27-SEP-19  | 29-SEP-19
3       | 30-SEP-19  | 02-OCT-19
4       | 03-OCT-19  | 04-OCT-19
4;5     | 05-OCT-19  | 07-OCT-19
4       | 08-OCT-19  | 10-OCT-19
6       | 11-OCT-19  | 13-OCT-19
```

Comment: Many thanks! That solved the problem. I had to edit my PL/SQL procedure first in order to check on the "real data problem". Again, many thanks for the quick answer. You saved my weekend indeed ;)